# How to spawn process C++ from C#?

Tags: c#, aho-corasick, managed-cuda

I've a library in C++ to run a string matching (PFAC library)[PFAC-lib](https://github.com/pfac-lib/PFAC). How do i run this library from  WinForm C#?

I also used [managedCuda](https://github.com/kunzmi/managedCuda) to run cuda code from my C#. Any idea?

Comment: Check the [official doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/55d3thsc.aspx) on calling c++ from managed code.

Comment: maybe [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern) will be helpful also

Comment: @Potato thanks for your advice.. but can i run it in winform?

Comment: @bradbury9 your reference link is in c++.. is there anything in c#? thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"PFAC library provides C-style API. Programmers can link the library to C/C++ code or other language."

You should be able to dllimport the parts you need for the code to work.

but you might have a hard time as i just looked at the struct create needs. good luck

Comment: how can i import "the parts" that i want ? is create new c++ file and then debug to dll and then import it in c#? is that possible? how about the cu file? hahaha.. I'm sorry for the burden

Comment: an example of this would be
[DllImport(nativeLibName, EntryPoint = "PFAC_create")]
public static extern IntPtr PFAC_create(IntPtr PfHandle);

You would need to create replicas of the structs in c# to meet the creation requirements tho

Comment: I've got only 24 hours to finish it.. And i'm also new to CUDA. My thought would be anything but without convert it manually in C#. But it seems impossible